# Positivstellensatz for non-polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, positive-characteristic, real-algebraic-geometry

Can we use Positivstellensatz (P-satz) below for a **non-polynomial** term?

P-satz:
Let $R$ be real closed field. Let $f,g,h$ be finite families of **polynomials** in $R[X_{1} ,...,X_{n}]$. Denote by P the cone generated by $f$, $M$ the multiplicative monoid generated by $g$ and $I$ the ideal generated by $h$. Then the following properties are equivalent:

(i) The set ${x\in R^n| f\geq 0, g\neq 0 , h=0}$ is empty
(ii) There exist $f \in P, g\in M, h\in I$ such that $f+g^2 +h=0$.

Reference:
Bochnak et al. 1999

Comment: What do you mean with non-polynomial term?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. :), What I mean by non-polynomial term are, trigonometric functions (e.g. $\sin x$) or a logarithmic functions (e.g. $\log x$) or the combination of functions (e.g. $x \sin x$) or else.

Comment: How would you define $\cos x$ over a real (real-algebraically) closed field that is not the real numbers and is not topologically closed?

Comment: @LutzL I am sorry I don't understand your question (since I am new in modern algebra),,,What I want to do is to apply P-satz when $f,g,h$ are not polynomials, but a functions. I need to simplify analysis of a nonlinear system. (I am really sorry for the lack of knowledge of mathematics, I just started learning it.)

Comment: Over the real or complex numbers, $\cos(x)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$, so you have to make sure that you have a topological limit in your general real field, and that division by all integers is allowed. Which restricts the field to characteristic $0$,...

Comment: So if I restrict the field to characteristic 0, I can use some  functions beside polyomials for $f,g,h$?